# Swift - Bind generic parameter in switch statement

Tags: swift, generics, switch-statement

When using Enumerations with Switches, you can bind associated values to variables. For example:

```
let x: Int? = 5

switch x {
case .some(let wrapped):
    print(wrapped) //Assosiated value bound to "wrapped"
case .none:
    print("nil")
}
```

Is there a similar way to bind generic type parameters? Here's the type of semantics I'm looking for:

```
func foo(_ arg: T) {
    switch arg {
    case array as Array<let X>:
        print("The argument is an array of \(X)")
    default:
        print("The argument is not an array")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to check if argument is Array? Try this:

```
func foo<T>(arr: Array<T>) {
    print("argument is array of \(T.self)")

    switch T.self {
        case is Int.Type:
            print("integer array")
        default:
            print("Unknown type or empty")
    }
}
```

then you can pass only array as argument without useless checking.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Mirror` - it's contrived, and not exactly the syntax you were looking for, but how about:

```
func isItACollection(_ any: Any) -> [String : Any.Type]? {
    let m = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    switch m.displayStyle {
    case .some(.collection):
        // `.children` gives us the actual types of the elements
        // This may be heterogeneous, so we spoof a Set of types
        // by using a dictionary
        var types: [String: Any.Type] = [:]
        for (_, t) in m.children {
            types["\(type(of: t))"] = type(of: t)
        }
        return types
    default: 
        return nil
    }
}

func test(_ a: Any) -> String {
    switch isItACollection(a) {
    case .some(let X):
        return "The argument is an array of \(X)"
    default:
        return "The argument is not an array"
    }
}

test([1, 2, 3]) // The argument is an array of ["Int": Swift.Int]
test([1, 2, "3"]) // The argument is an array of ["Int": Swift.Int, "String": Swift.String]
test(["1", "2", "3"]) // The argument is an array of ["String": Swift.String]
test(Set<String>()) // The argument is not an array
test([1: 2, 3: 4]) // The argument is not an array
test((1, 2, 3)) // The argument is not an array
test(3) // The argument is not an array
test("3") // The argument is not an array
test(NSObject()) // The argument is not an array
test(NSArray(array:[1, 2, 3])) // The argument is an array of ["_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber": _SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't do =/ 1) I'd like just the generic type, such as `String`, rather than `Array<String>`. 2) I'd like to be able to do this for any arbitrary generic type, such as `Set`, `Dictionary` or anything else.

Comment: You just have to do a little more reflection - docs are here https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror. I've updated the answer to return actual types, though you have to be careful with mixed arrays. I leave your point 2) which was beyond the OQ as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know the generic type, you can do:

```
func checkType<T>(_ arg: Array<T>) {
    print("The argument is an Array of type \(type(of: T.self))")
}

func checkType<T>(_ arg: T) {
    print("The argument is of type \(type(of: T.self))")
}

checkType([1])
checkType(1)
// The argument is an Array of type Int.Type
// The argument is of type Int.Type
```

However, if you also want to bind the values which the generic type holds:

```
func showValue<T>(from arg: T) {
    switch arg {
    case let value as Array<Any>:
        print("value is \(value)")
    case let value as Int:
        print("value is \(value)")
    default:
        print("couldn't get value")
    }
}

showValue(from: [1])
showValue(from: 1)
// value is [1]
// value is 1
```